# Data rendering with beforemount in Vuejs keep multiplying the list of data renderd every time I open that component/page

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am pulling data from Firestore in a method and pass it to mount/beforemount to show on the screen. But whenever I re-open the page (navigate to a different page and come back) it renders the same list again and again.(like 2 items become 4 and 6 and so on)

```
dataitems() {
      db.collection("Orders")
        .get()
        .then( (querySnapshot)=> {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
          //  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            var list= doc.data()
           this.$store.commit('firebaseList',list)
          });
        });
    },
```

And this is the mount life-cycle hook

```
  mounted(){
    return this.dataitems()
  },
```

My vuex code is this:

```
state()
{
return{
FirebaseList=[],
}},
mutations:{
firebaseList(state,items){
   state.FirebaseList.replace(items)
  },
getters:{
getFirebaseList(state){
      return state.FirebaseList
    }
}
```

Comment: because data gets persisted to vuex store each time, i think

Comment: @NileshPatel What Can I do to solve it?

Comment: Can <keep-alive> solve it? If yes how to use it, because I tried to wrap the whole component in it but, it didn't work.

Comment: in vuex mutation, replace data, do not append it like this `state.list=list`

Comment: @NileshPatel I cant not replace it because I am making that component for admin to add items. Like a burger. So, I have to push.

Answer (score 0):

You are comitting to the Vuex store everytime dataItems() is called. This could be solved by simply changing to commit to an action or mutation that replaced all the items in the firebaseList. Then to load the data you would then create a Getter in your store that would then return the firebaseList

Like this example:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: initialState(),
mutations: {
    updateList(state, payload) {
        state.firebaseList = payload;
    }
},
getters: {
    getFirebaseList(state) {
        return state.firebaseList;
    },
}
});
```

Then to load your data  in mounted:

```
  import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    mounted(){
      this.firebaseList = this.getFirebaseList;
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapGetters(["getFirebaseList"]),
    }
```

Comment: Firebaselist is array so have to use push. I am doing like this "  firebaseList(state,items){
    state.FirebaseList.push(items)
  }, "

Comment: First, mapGetters should use computed. your code is not rendering the firebase function that I post in question.

Comment: First off. mapGetters do not need to be in computed... I provived the example above as a guideline. So you could see exactly what you were missing. It seems like you do not know how to apply vuex in your application. If you were to do this correctly following the vuex pattern, you would have the call to firebase inside the vuex actions to update the state and then listen for the updates inside the component